# What is the default value of `ExecSearchPath=` in a systemd unit file?

Tags: systemd, systemd-unit

`man systemd.exec` says concerning [`ExecSearchPath=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#ExecSearchPath=):

> Takes a colon separated list of absolute paths relative to which the executable used by the Exec*= (e.g. ExecStart=, ExecStop=, etc.) properties can be found. ExecSearchPath= overrides $PATH if $PATH is not supplied by the user through Environment=, EnvironmentFile= or PassEnvironment=. Assigning an empty string removes previous assignments and setting ExecSearchPath= to a value multiple times will append to the previous setting.

What is the default value of `ExecSearchPath=`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default binary search path is described [in the section on command lines](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Command%20lines):

> If the command is not a full (absolute) path, it will be resolved to a full path using a fixed search path determined at compilation time. Searched directories include `/usr/local/bin/`, `/usr/bin/`, `/bin/` on systems using split `/usr/bin/` and `/bin/` directories, and their `sbin/` counterparts on systems using split `bin/` and `sbin/`. It is thus safe to use just the executable name in case of executables located in any of the "standard" directories, and an absolute path must be used in other cases. Using an absolute path is recommended to avoid ambiguity. Hint: this search path may be queried using **systemd-path search-binaries-default**.

The default value of `ExecSearchPath` itself is empty, which triggers the behaviour above.

(Note that `ExecSearchPath` is very recent, it was added in systemd 250.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In systemd before 250, what was the value of serach paths where systemd searches for non-absolute path to binaries ?

Comment: @socketpair it was the same. systemd 250 added `ExecSearchPath`, it didn’t change the default search paths.

Comment: \@stephen-kitt where to read about these defaults ? where to read about these defaults ?

Comment: @socketpair follow the link at the top of my answer.